# How can one manage front-end library dependencies in Clojure?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clojure, ring, compojure

I have a Clojure Ring/Compojure web project with Javascript front-end. I want to use Bootstrap CSS library for the front-end. Right now i'd download it and put into `resources/public/lib/bootstrap`. But it would be nice to manage JS/CSS libs similarly to `:dependencies` list in `project.clj`. How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, i've stumbled upon right after posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bower fulfils my requirements. Prerequisites are installing Bower through NPM and [lein-bower](https://github.com/chlorinejs/lein-bower) Leiningen plugin. Below are the configuration details I had to add to `project.clj`:

```
:plugins [[lein-bower "0.5.1"]]
:bower-dependencies [[bootstrap "3.3.2"]]
:bower {:directory "resources/public/lib"}
```

@Aleš Roubíček - thanks for your comment.